# How to - multiple Meteor apps on single MongoDB - same collections?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

This kind of question has been asked before:
[How can I share MongoDB collections between Meteor apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13115723/how-can-i-share-mongodb-collections-between-meteor-apps)

However, the answer is not clear.

I need to have a Meteor public app and the Administration app separate (for many reasons, but mainly security and code management).

Using the accepted answer: export MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:3002/meteor seems reasonable, but below another user 'matthias' points out "When connecting from another app, events that trigger changes in the model would not be transported across those applications. The mongoDB instance itself of course isn't aware of that."

How does one trigger the 'other' meteor app to reevaluate the events/triggers from the MongoDB? Meaning simply **if I make a change in the administration module, how can I make the public site reflect those changes?** Assuming that is what was meant. Also is there any other functionality that will be lost by this method?

Thanks

Comment: You can make a change in the database via the mongo console, and the Meteor app will still pick it up, and very quickly if it observes the DB via oplog tailing.

Comment: So you are saying cross-app updates are not an issue? I was under the impression that each Meteor App is closely related to its MongoDB instance. Not sure it makes sense that other Meteor Apps would 'listen' to 'other' mongo collections.

Comment: This isn't an issue. Mongodb instances are in no way tied to an application. As long as they are sharing the same instance via MONGO_URL all of the magic will happen the way you want it to.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is that you don't have to do anything. As long as the apps use the same database (as identified by the `MONGO_URL`), they will respond reactively to changes in the data.

In fact separating your app into a front-end and a back-end is a good strategy, as outlined in this video, [Why you should split your meteor app](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aYIK_ClHLZo).

You can even use the `mongo` shell to update/insert/delete documents in the database, and the publications will pick them up.

Comment: Heads-up when inserting directly into MongoDB though... IDs are different than from docs inserted via Meteor.

Comment: Hey , I am making the same thing as mentioned by  mfr in his question. I am getting one problem when ever I insert data in MongoDb my app does not reflect the inserted data automatically I always need to refresh it manually  in order to see the new inserted data in my Ui.here is my :-
process.env.MONGO_URL = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test_db';

Comment: @sid: hard to diagnose that and besides the scope of this answer. You should check your subscriptions, esp. if you use iron-router, and post a new question if you still need help.

Comment: Hey Dan, have a look on my new question.Here is its link :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31472976/push-notification-integration-in-meteor