# Push notification integration in meteor

Tags: android, mongodb, cordova, meteor, push-notification

I am having two applications one is for admin and another is for users.I want to implement push notification in it so that when ever user rate the offer in application then Admin can get notification of it with user phone-number and rating count.I found one good example of push notification but unable to implement in my application as its storing data in local mongoDb not in main so that my other application do not get the stored value in order to hit push notification.I am stuck at this point. can any one provide me a simple approach/process to achieve my goal.I am really new to meteor and have not much knowledge about it.
To implement Push-Notification I am taking reference of :-

1) https://github.com/richsilv/meteor-cordova-notifications/

2) https://github.com/richsilv/cordova-notifications-demo

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend using Parse:

https://parse.com/docs

They make push notifications super easy, and for an affordable price.

Comment: Can any one tell me that,Is there any way by which i can store my regId of Gcm in my main server database which is accessible to my both applications ?I am really stuck at this point ...any help ?