# 2 meteor apps connecting same Database

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have two different meteor apps. app1 running on 3000 and app2 running on 3002. So my question is both app1 and app2 should use same Database. I tried connecting app2 with "export MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:3001/app1" but went fruitless.

How would I be able to accomplish this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I share MongoDB collections between Meteor apps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13115723/how-can-i-share-mongodb-collections-between-meteor-apps)

Comment: Which of course means the real answer here is to use a "separate and shared" instance of MongoDB for both applications rather than try to connect one application to the other app's datbase instance.

Comment: I used "MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/my_db" to connect both apps, but not connecting.

Comment: You need to start an "independant" MongoDB. In the real world this is what you do. You will **never** deploy both MongoDB and "multiple" apps ( or even one ) on the same server instance. Learn the lesson please.

Answer (score 0):

The standard database meteor creates is called meteor, so I think you should start your second meteor instance with:

```
MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:3001/meteor meteor -p 3002
```

Comment: this creates a new instance of mongodb at 3003

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10:

1. In App-1 start with meteor
2. Open second Powershell: cd path/to/APP-1
3. Enter: meteor mongo
4. In Line> connecting to: copy complete mongodb-URL something like:
   mongodb://127.0.0.1:3001/meteor?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
5. exit from mongo-shell
6. cd path/to/APP-2
7. Create a meteor_start.bat file
   8.Open with Editor meteor_start.bat type (!!!Attention & -> ^& in Mongo-URL):
   SET MONGO_URL=mongodb://127.0.0.1:3001/meteor?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb & meteor --port 3500
8. Save meteor_start.bat
9. Powershell > cd path/to/APP-2
10. enter cmd
11. enter meteor_start.bat

Result:
App-1 running at localhost 3000
App-2 running at localhost 3500

App-1 & App2 using same local mongodb at mongodb://127.0.0.1:3001

Have Fun