# Meteor: Mongod.lock when running multiple instance

Tags: mongodb, meteor, locking

I'm doing a Meteor app where I can have multiple users. I want to run two instances of the app.

So I do `meteor --port 3001` from a terminal and `meteor --port 3002` from another teminal.

The first instance works fine and launch properly the app. The second returns an error :

`Error: EBUSY, unlink 'C:\Users\userName\Desktop\myAppName\.meteor\local\db\mongod.lock'`

So I assume mongodb lock the database... So how can I test my app when multiple users are using it on the same time ?

Thanks :=)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I share MongoDB collections between Meteor apps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13115723/how-can-i-share-mongodb-collections-between-meteor-apps)

Comment: You don't need multiple app instances, you only need multiple browsers.

Comment: BTW, take a look at https://github.com/anticoders/gagarin

Comment: @apendua Perfect and simple. Thanks.